# Can't setup Android SDK on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-sdk-manager

I just installed my VS2015 enterprise and  I want to try "cross platform" or "Android blank App" project, but in both , I got a message box with this error

> Value cannot be null
>   Parameter name:path1

When I try to run Tools/Android /Android SDK Manager I got a Visual Studio error:

> Error: Command did not execute uccessfully due to an unexpected exeption.Please check the output window for aditional information

In the error window I got

> Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please set Android SDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu

[image]

When  I open  start/all programs/Android SDK tools/SDK Manager/tools/options
[image]

After a while  I got this:
[image]

It looks like it can't download something, I guess there is no Android SDK installed on my PC.

I've tried disabling my firewall but it's the same, any idea?

Comment: Are you running VS 2015 (and SDK Manager) as admin?

Comment: yes I do run as admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JDK and Android NDK Locations paths might be properly set but SDK might be not set. Even i had the same problem. I solved it in three steps . If you have the same problem as shown above Image, then follow these steps.

1. Click on Change, it will show Folders.
2. Select this Path `****C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk****`
   For all the systems, the SDK will be located in this location only.
3. Click on Ok. now your Android SDk manager will be in Enable. Your Problem will solve.

Incase your android-sdk not located in this place, then you need to search for android-sdk where it is located.
If you dont find android-sdk in C Drive, it may not be installed properly. 
Here we have two Options.

1. Open vstoolsforxamarin.exe and select the tools which we need and update them (or)
2. You can install android-sdk manually.

here is the link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/.

My suggestions is don't Uninstall and install VS, its unnecessary headache.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is ANDROID SDK manager installed in your machine.

I have same problem with this because our network are behind proxy. What I do is fill in the HTTP proxy server IP and port. Then try to update the components one more time.
This time you will prompted to key in the user name and password for every component that is currently being installed.

Somehow still failed.

So my another attempt is just key in the user name with a blank password. And then its working, and updated of ANDROID SDK components has been done successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I set the path like this: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
and the problem solved.
I found the solution in this link.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-sdk-location/

Answer (score 0):

The **adb.exe** should be available in android sdk folder. If it is not there then Visual Studio will not detect it.